# Android MVP and Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, mvp

I have just started a new project using MVP. There seems to be quite a lack of structured information regarding this approach, especially examples or details of how to apply this to the navigation drawer.

Is there a preferred method or any examples that anyone knows of?

Comment: We use a navigation drawer which switches between an inbox, outbox, form section etc. The user clicks on a menu item which tells the presenter an action occured. The presenter then decides which fragment to load and tells the view or wireframe to load it?.

Answer (score 1):

use something like this [example](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-interactor-architecture/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mindorks/framework/mvp/ui/main/MainActivity.java)